# Track changes of sale and cost prices in odoo 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

i am trying to track changes over sale and cost price in  **odoo 8** by inheriting product.product model and change track visibility of `price_list` and `standard_cost` but no changes.
any hint please.

models.py:

```py
from openerp.osv import osv, fields, expression
import openerp.addons.decimal_precision as dp


class product_template(osv.osv):

_name = 'product.template'
_inherit = 'product.template'


 _columns = {
    'list_price': fields.float('Sale Price',track_visibility='onchange', digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Product Price'),
                               help="Base price to compute the customer price. Sometimes called the catalog price."),

}
```

Comment: Show us how you use the `track_visibility` attribute please.

Comment: i have added my model file

Comment: You've written "by inheriting `product.product` model", but actually have overridden `product.template`.

Comment: can you provide more details please.

Answer (score 1):

For tracking changes, you should add some more options, such as

You should do `_inherit = ['mail.thread']` in your model

Secondly, add a chatter option in form view like this

```
<div class="oe_chatter">
     <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers" help="Follow this project to automatically track the events associated to tasks and issues of this project." groups="base.group_user"/>
     <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
</div>
```